# How to import the data to add graphs to Keynote?

Tags: iwork-keynote

I want to be able to add graphs to keynote (such as line graphs). It seems like I have to put down the data manually in the table they give. Isn't there a way to read the data from a text file or something like that?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! But this being a Q&A site: please do not combine multiple questions into a single post, and please make titles summarize a question. To avoid people would answer both questions before you read my comment: I have already deleted part of it. Please click [here](http://superuser.com/posts/221998/revisions) to see your previous version, and copy the remaining part into a new question. Thanks and success!

Answer (score 3):

You can, for example, paste the data from a text file, as Keynote accepts Tab and Newline characters as field and line delimiters. Any source that provides data in this format will do, and you can even copy & paste directly from tables in `Numbers.app`.

Start by copying your data into the clipboard:
(SuperUser converts my tabs to spaces, I don't think it will work if you just copy this, but you get the idea)

```
Foo 1   4   5   8   4
Bar 6   7   5   4   8
```

First, select the first line into which you want to paste your data:

[image]

Then, Press `Cmd-V` to paste the data in the clipboard to the table:
[image]

While not as good as having full flexibility in how you input your data, it's better than nothing.

Comment: Nice! Am I right to assume that pasting from some spreadsheet would not require one to first create a text file? (Hope you did not waste time on answering that 2nd question as well? Or let's assume the question asker will come back to repost that 2nd part!)

Comment: @Arjan I saw this Q only after your edits. You don't need a text file, generally anything that provides its data with tab delimiters and newlines will do, but it might depend on the formats the programs supports. I can directly paste Numbers table selection into the data table of Keynote. If I paste `Numbers.app` data to plain text, it's converted into the same tab/newline delimited format too.

Comment: This works, but note there are some quirks. For example, if you want to paste in column and row headers, you need to make sure the upper left corner cell of your source is blank. If there's content in that upper left cell, Keynote will paste into the row headers but not the column headers.